# What content-type would this response be?

Tags: api, http-headers, response

So I am working on implementing an endpoint for an API. The response returns a map with the file map as the key and the contents as a value.

For example:

```
{
"FileName": "Contents",
"FileName": "Contents"
}
```

Would this be application/json or text/plain?

Comment: I would say application/json

Comment: Yeah, I was leaning more towards application/json. Thanks.